# Flow control in Exception Handling

Tags: java, exception, try-catch-finally

I am fairly new to Java and unable to understand the flow of control in try-catch-finally blocks. Whenever a exception is caught in a catch block, the code after the catch block is also executed, whether I place it in a finally block or not. Then what is the use of finally block?

```
class Excp
{
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
  int a,b,c;
  try
  {
   a=0;
   b=10;
   c=b/a;
   System.out.println("This line will not be executed");
  }
  catch(ArithmeticException e)
  {
   System.out.println("Divided by zero"); 
  }
  System.out.println("After exception is handled");
 }
}
```

There is no difference if I place the last print statement inside the finally block.

Comment: Throw a `new RuntimeException()` inside the `try` and you'll notice that the code after the catch block isn't executed. Then add a finally block.

Comment: You use the `finally` block to set your program to a status it can work with after any exception happened.

Comment: The code inside the finally block **always** executes, even if in the `try` or `catch` there is a `return` or an unhandled exception.
This is explained [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) which was found with a really easy google search. **Please use google.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes a difference if another exception (unhandled by your code) happens in the `try/catch` block.

Without `finally`, the last line wouldn't be executed. With `finally`, the code is executed no matter what.

This is particularly useful to perform cleanup tasks beyond the reach of the garbage collector: system ressource, database lock, file deletion etc...

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

```
try {
    a=0;
    b=10;
    c=b/a;
    System.out.println("This line will not be executed");
}
catch(ArithmeticException e){
    throw new RuntimeException("Stuff went wrong", e); 
}
System.out.println("This line will also not be executed");
```

Answer (score 1):

the finally block can be used to be executed, even after a function returns.

e.g.

```
public boolean doSmth() {
  try {
   return true;
  }
  finally {
    return false;
  }
}
```

would return false;

Answer (score 0):

The `finally` block will also execute if an exception is thrown from the `catch` block, or if a different exception is thrown from the `try` block.

examples:

```
try {
  int a=5;
  int b=0;
  int c=a/b;
catch (NullPointerException e) {
  // won't reach here
} finally {
  // will reach here
}
```

You may also omit the catch block entirely and still guarantee that the finally block will be executed:

```
try {
  int a=5;
  int b=0;
  int c=a/b;
} finally {
  // will reach here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code inside the finally block **always** executes, even if in the `try` or `catch` there is a `return` or an unhandled exception.
This is explained [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html), which was found with a really easy google search. **Please use google.**